# JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Should I use hibernate instead of JPA? What's the difference

Comment: please make clear question

Comment: are you asking whether you should use JPA or Hibernate?

Comment: despite the question being asked in poor English, it still makes some sense.

Comment: I took the freedom to rephrase the question.

Answer (score 5):

Hibernate *is* JPA.

JPA is a standard. Multiple vendors can provide implementation of that standard. Hibernate is one implementation of JPA. Of course it has additional features, but it supports the whole standard.

So the best thing to do is - use Hibernate (or EclipseLink - another implementation), and apply only JPA-stuff - `javax.persistence.*` annotations, and configuration via `persistence.xml` (rather than `hibernate.cfg.xml`)